# Could not find play-services-auth-base-license.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base-license:11.8.0)

Tags: ionic3, build.gradle

My Gradle was like this two days ago but suddenly this error appeared:

Error: /project/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

**A problem occurred configuring root project 'project'. Here is the exact error:
Could not find play-services-auth-base-license.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base-license:11.8.0).**

Searched in the following locations with no help:

https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth-base-license/11.8.0/ play-services-auth-base-license-11.8.0.aar

Few days ago all was fine, today i had tried rebuild app (without any changes) got Error. This error is only for Android build for iOS its working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the people who are using ionic as a mobile wrapper.

what solved my problem first was:

1) cordova plugin add cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release  --variable PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION={required version} 
   the version that I used was 11.6.2

2) go to ionic_folder/platforms/android/build.gradle

If you see this lines of code in your file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }

    }
```

Change the order of the executions

```
  buildscript {
    repositories {

        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()

    }
```

Then go again and run your application by doing
ionic cordova run android --livereload --device

Answer (score 5):

try to reverse jcenter and maven **repositories call order** in your build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```